# Trick to explicit choose overloaded method without static_cast

Tags: c++

This is a question mainly about making the code easier on the eyes.

I have a template class `t<T, Ts...>` that generates an overloaded method, `overloaded_method(x<T> *)`, for each template argument `T`. The argument on this method is not of the template argument type directly but for some other specialization template class, `x<T>`.

So, given `class a` and `class b`, we have `t<a,b>` which has `overloaded_method(x<a> *)` and `overloaded_method(x<b> *)`.

After that I create an implementation class `impl` that implements `x<a>` and `x<b>`.

If I try to call `overloaded_method()` with an object `ii` of `impl`, the compiler doesn't know if it has to choose `overloaded_method(x<a> *)` or `overloaded_method(x<b> *)`, which is understandable.

I can help the compiler by using static_cast. Eg. `ti.overloaded_method(static_cast<x<a> *>(&ii))`.

This works fine, but feels like a thorn in the eye, and wouldn't be nice for a user of my library. I would rather do something like `ti.overloaded_method<a>(&ii)`, which is invalid.

Is there any way to explicitly choose which overloaded method to use, that doesn't involve `static_cast` and `x`?

```
template<typename T>
class x {
public:
    T *v;
};

template<typename...>
class t {
public:
    void overloaded_method();
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class t<T, Ts...>: public t<Ts...> {
public:
    void overloaded_method(x<T> *v) {
    }
    using t<Ts...>::overloaded_method;
};


class a
{
};
class b {
};

class impl: public x<a>,
            public x<b> {
};

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    t<a, b> ti;
    impl ii;

    ti.overloaded_method(static_cast<x<b> *>(&ii));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Through [SFINAE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7e6cfc7ef68ddac)

Comment: Your problem statement is clear, but a bit too abstract. If you tell more about what you are designing exactly, there might be an entirely different solution...

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I tried to use an extra `template <typename X>` in the method, but didn't know about the `std::enable_if_t...`.